# MySQL: Group rows by column value prefix

Tags: mysql

I have a table with records like this

```
(title)
ABC 001
ABC 002
DEF 001
DEF 002
... ...
```

and I want to get only one for each that starts with the same string. For example in this case, I expect 2 records, `ABC 001` and `DEF 001`.

Is it possible with MySQL alone, or I have to do it within the application after I get all records ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do using mysql only  with a group by on substr

```
 select min(title )
 from my_table
 group by substr(title, 1,3)
```

or for variable space position

```
  select min(title )
 from my_table
 group by substr(title, 1,locate(' ' , title))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, just one more thing. Would it be possible to split by a space character ? I'm asking because not all titles begin with exactly 3 characters, others may have 2 or 4. But every one has a space between the prefix and the string after

Comment: Yes using locate you can manage variable space position  ..  answer updated

Answer (score 1):

You could split your title with string functions (e.g. `MID()`) and create 2 columns. After this you `GROUP BY` the result by one column.

`SELECT MID(title, 0, 3) AS B, MID(title, 3, 3) AS B FROM table GROUP BY B`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_mid

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply, just one more thing. Would it be possible to split by a space character ? I'm asking because not all titles begin with exactly 3 characters, others may have 2 or 4. But every one has a space between the prefix and the string after

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split the strings on the space character, and then group by the first string and select the min value for the second string, you can do so like this:

```
select substr1, min(substr2)
from
(
  select substring_index(title, ' ', 1) AS substr1,
    substring_index(title, ' ', -1) AS substr2
  from your_table
) sub_query 
group by substr1
```